# A convergent sequence specified recursively by a continuous function $f$ converges to a fixed point of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I conjecture, and would like to prove: A convergent sequence specified recursively by a continuous function $f$ converges to a fixed point of $f$.  That is, $f$ must have at least one fixed point, one of which is the limit of the sequence.

First, let's state this conjecture formally:

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$.  I conjecture that if $(x_n)$ converges to a limit $\ell$, and $f$ is continuous, then $f(\ell) = \ell$.

(Continuity is clearly required, as evidenced by $x_n = 1, f(x) = \{x/2$ for $x > 0,$ otherwise $1\}$.)

**Proof:** Consider the sequence $(F_n)$, such that $F_1 = x_1$ and $F_{n+1} = f(x_n)$.  Since, $F_n = x_n$,

$$
\ell = \lim_{n \to \infty} F_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)
$$

Since $f$ is continuous,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n) = f(\ell).$$

Thus,
$$ \ell = f(\ell),$$

QED.

Is this proof correct? Can any steps be omitted? It seems to me more complex than I expected, yet I can't find a step that is superfluous.

Comment: Your formal statement and proof is fine, but in your first paragraph you make a stronger claim that is false. It's not true that $f$ must have a fixed point (consider e.g. $f(x) = x^2 + 1$), and even if it does it's not true that $x_n$ necessarily converges at all. What is true, and what you've proven, is that *if* $x_n$ converges then it converges to a fixed point of $f$ (meaning $f$ has at least one fixed point).

Comment: Also you can streamline the proof a bit as follows: by definition we have $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$. If $x_n$ converges, taking the limit of both sides gives $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+1} = \ell = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n) = f(\ell)$. It's not necessary to introduce a second sequence which is just also equal to $x_n$...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Can you clarify? I stated "A convergent sequence," meaning that $x_n$ converges. To my knowledge, there is no sequence $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + 1$ that converges.  I maintain my statement "A convergent sequence specified recursively by a continuous function f converges to a fixed point of f" is indeed true.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I skipped over the word "convergent." Yes, this is all fine.